# sccm with distributed clients not in AD

Tags: active-directory, sccm, point-of-sale

Before I go through learning about sccm can you guys tell me if it is possible to update and organize Pos systems, windows updates, software updates,  which are not within an ad domain...How does this work is it workgroup etc. and online links much appreciated....

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible:

[How to Install Configuration Manager Clients on Workgroup Computers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb680962.aspx)

also here look at [Managing Workgroup Clients in SCCM](http://blogs.technet.com/sudheesn/archive/2009/12/30/managing-workgroup-clients-in-sccm.aspx)